# Ionic Tabs are not showing after I login to my app

Tags: html, typescript, ionic3

hello I have a app i'm working on that when a valid username and password is entered the app redirects the user to the events page which is part of a tab controller but this is what it looks like when the user loges into the app: [image]

here's is my code for the login page.html:

```
<ion-content padding id="page6">
  <img src="assets/img/pDQnyrguQAqrcKYvyqqa_web_hi_res_512.png" style="display:block;width:60%;height:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" />
  <form id="login-form3">
    <ion-card id="login-card24">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-list id="login-list2">
          <ion-item id="login-input1">
            <ion-label>
              Email
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item id="login-input2">
            <ion-label>
              Password
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-card>
    <div class="spacer" style="height:40px;" id="login-spacer1"></div>
    <button id="login-button1" ion-button (click)="login(user)" color="dark" block>
      Log in
    </button>
    <button id="login-button2" ion-button clear color="positive" block on-click="goToSignup()">
      Or create an account
    </button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

here's the login.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';
import { User } from "../../app/models/user";
import{AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { EventsPage } from '../events/events';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

    user = {} as User;

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,

        public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

    async login(user: User) {
        try {
            const result = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(EventsPage);


        }

        catch (e) {

            console.error(e);
        }
    }

  goToSignup(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(SignupPage);
  }
}
```

and the events.html page:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      Events
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding id="page3">
  <ion-card id="events-card26">
    <ion-list>
      <form id="events-form6">
        <ion-searchbar placeholder="" name="" id="events-search3"></ion-searchbar>
      </form>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

and finally the events.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-events',
  templateUrl: 'events.html'
})
export class EventsPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }



}
```

I know its most likely a easy fix but i'm new to ionic so I apologize in advance, and any help would be amazing!

Thanks in  advance! :)

Comment: which is the page with the tabs ..the onw having `ion-tabs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your Tabs Page from 'EventsPage.ts'.
Call it using 'setRoot' option.
Example :

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(PageName);
```

Ref : PageName > Your Tabs page class name